# Better bound for an equation of sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, upper-lower-bounds, geometric-series

For the following equation, is there a better bound than the trivial bound I proposed $$ \Bigl( a \sum_{x=1}^n [\ x^d-(x-1)^d]\ \exp\Bigl\{-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}\Bigr\} +\sum_{x=1}^n x^{d-2}\exp\Bigl\{-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}\Bigr\} \Bigr) \\\leq (a+1)\sum_{x=1}^n x^d\exp\Bigl\{-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}\Bigr\} ~\text{as}~n~ \text{is large.} $$

This trivial upperbound seems large and I am looking for a tighter one. I thought about $ [\ x^d-(x-1)^d]\ = [\ (x-1+1)^d-(x-1)^d]$ but I don't have an idea how to continue!

I would be thankful for any help

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $d\geq 1$, one has
$$
x^d-(x-1)^d=x^d(1-(1-1/x)^d)\leq x^d(1-(1-d/x))=dx^{d-1}
$$
using [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), which obtains a slightly better bound of
$$
(ad+1)\sum_{x=1}^n x^{d-1}\exp(-x^2/\sigma^2).
$$

Comment: then to continue as $$
(ad+1)\sum_{x=1}^n x^{d-1}\exp(-x^2/\sigma^2) \leq (ad+1)\sum_{x=1}^n x^{d}\exp(-x^2/\sigma^2)
$$
or there is a better idea?

Comment: If you continue that way, you get an unconditionally worse bound than what you originally wrote. What I wrote is better when $\sigma^2$ isn't too small (as otherwise only the first few terms in the sum are nonnegligible) because $dx^{d-1}<x^d$ for $x>d$. So it really depends on how large $\sigma^2$ and $a$ are.

Comment: In fact I am doing this is to lowerbound $\sigma^2$! here $x,d \rightarrow \infty$ but I can't say $x > d$!

so,as I see, simplifying it will send me also to the same solution